# php array_intersect not returning correct values

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying two get same value from 2 array.

First Array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => sku
  [1] => qty

)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => sku
  [1] => qty

)
```

and *array_intersect* returns below result:

```
Array
(
 [0] => sku
)
```

if I user below if conditon

```
    if ($newArray == $oldArray) 
    echo "Both arrays are same\n"; 
                        else
    echo "Both arrays are not same\n";
```

it returns "Both arrays are same".

I guess this can be problem

[image]

which one should I trust?
what I am doing wrong in this? Please help

Thanks

Comment: `array_diff($first_array, $second_array)`

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/MMz67rQWv2Qg32wXrcSIEA?language=php this works perfect. But check with `var_dump` might be your data type change.

Comment: `array_diff` is what you need if both are match then you get an empty array else the non match value. But its comares the first over second so unmatch will be return from the first array.. you can count the result to know if it match or not.

Comment: is there any more space in your array value?

Comment: i thinks there is no extra space in array. @TsaiKoga

Comment: can u post your `array_intersact` code?

Comment: $newMatchedArray = array_intersect($newArray,$oldArray);   @TsaiKoga

Comment: stop using `print_r` ... use something like `var_dump` or `dump` and it will become obvious the difference in the values

Comment: no help @lagbox

Comment: How do I remove space at end of an array?

Comment: okay, well your values are not the same in both arrays, it is as simple as that

Comment: that I am removing from trim fucntion

Comment: this array with space is coming from csv @lagbox

Answer (score 0):

This returns the results you expect it would seem:

```
array_intersect(['sku', 'qty'], ['sku', 'qty']);

=> [
 "sku",
 "qty",
]
```

Comment: if I do static code, this result is fine,but from PHP file it is not, any idea?

Comment: would mean the values aren't the same

Answer (score 0):

I got the result using `array_intersect`

```
$x = Array
(
  0 => 'sku',
  1 => 'qty'
);
$y = Array
(
  0 => 'sku',
  1 => 'qty'
);

$z = array_intersect($x,$y);

print_r($z);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
[0] => sku
[1] => qty
)
```

Comment: if I do static code, this result is fine,but from PHP file it is not, any idea?